# How to gather array of data from nested form

Tags: javascript, php

Hi Im trying to use javascript to allow admin to key in sizes,no of bags ,no of cartons available for a product. Since I can't use nested forms thus I use javascript inside form.I can achieve it using javascript but unable to gather all the data entered inside the textboxes.Only the very first entry displays.

Php to display the data entered

```
 $_SESSION['myInputs_all'][]=array($_POST["myInputs_d"],$_POST["myInputs_d1"],$_POST["myInputs_bags"],$_POST["myInputs_carton"]);
 print_r($_SESSION['myInputs_all']);
foreach ( $_SESSION['myInputs_all'] as $eachInput) 
{
     echo $eachInput . "<br>";

}
```

HTML

```
            <tr>
                <th>Size D(mm)</th>
                <th>Size D1(mm)</th>
                <th>No of Bags</th>
                <th>No of Carton</th>
                </tr>   

               <div id="dynamicInput">


         <tr><td> Entry 1</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="myInputs_d" size='5'>
          <input type="text" name="myInputs_d1" size='5'>
          <input type="text" name="myInputs_bags" size='5'>
          <input type="text" name="myInputs_carton" size='5'></td>
         </tr>
     </div>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input"  name="myInputs[]" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

                                                         </td>  
                                                        </tr>
```

javascript

```
<script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' name='myInputs_d[]' size='5'><input type='text' name='myInputs_d1[]' size='5'><input type='text' name='myInputs_bags[]' size='5'><input type='text' name='myInputs_carton[]' size='5'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
```

When I print_r($_SESSION[myInputs_all]) it shows

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ujkopl [1] => jl[ [2] => uj [3] => juy ) ) Array
```

Answer (score 0):

try loop like this

```
 <?php for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION["myInputs_all"]);)?>
<tr> <td><?php echo $_SESSION["myInputs_all"][$i]['ItemDescription']; ?></td></tr>
```

"item description" is the index value that would be printed against each index i. 
in your code "myInputs_all" seems to be the array of session values. so printing each index will be the exact way.HTH

Comment: is this how u meant? for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION["myInputs_all"]);)?>
<tr> <td><?php echo $_SESSION["myInputs_all"][$i][$_POST["myInputs_d"]]; ?></td></tr>

Comment: just ignore <tr><td> tags in my post and set the for loop as it display the values against indexes. executer the for loop acc to no of session value using count. embed this for loop instead of your own